# Fetch search result from controller

Tags: ember.js

```
 App.Exam = DS.Model.extend({
 examType: attr('string'),
 examDate: attr('date'),
 gradeText: attr('string'),
 courseName: attr('string'),
 courseName__startswith: attr('string'),
 typeName: attr('string'),
 numberOf: attr('number'),
 grade: attr('number'), });
```

Here is the model that I want to access from the controller. I filter the model by using this

```
App.ExamController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  // the initial value of the `search` property
     search: ''

     ,query: function() {
     // the current value of the text field
     var queryCourseName = this.get('searchCourseName');
     this.set('searchResult',App.Exam.find({courseName: queryCourseName})

   }

 });
```

Is this the correct way to store the results of the `App.Exam.find()`? If it is how do I access the `searchResult` property from another controller and iterate through the values?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, but if you set the property `searchResult` on your `ExamController` doing this:

```
...
this.set('searchResult', App.Exam.find({courseName: queryCourseName}));
...
```

then you are later able, in another controller(s) to use the `needs` directive to gain access to your `ExamController`:

```
App.AnotherController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['exam'],
  examBinding: 'controllers.exam',
  ...
  myFunction: function() {
    this.get('exam.searchResult') // here are your values
  }
});
```

worth noting here is that the suffix `Binding` in `examBinding` tells ember to setup binding between the two properties, for more info check out the API doc's [Ember.Binding](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Binding.html)

hope it helps

Comment: When I try your solution I get an error at ' needs: ['exam'],
  examBinding: 'controllers.exam',' It says annot call method 'lookup' of null

Comment: hmm, could you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: It works when I use examBinding: 'App.ExamController.exam'. But I am still confused with how to accsess the values in the searchResult. Say that I want record nr 1 from the searchResult and get the examDate from that record, how can I achieve that?  Thx for the help so far!

Comment: how does `searchResult` look like? It's a collection of records? If so, your ExamController should extend from `Ember.ArrayController`. Where do you want to access the `searchResult`?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with a copy of the code from my application: [Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d5Xj/1/)  . The searchResult is of the type DS.RecordArray I think. I want to get data from the searchResult in the loadExamData function instead of just generate random values